# Efficiently create a big set of object

Tags: workflow, asset, random

I am creating a low poly forest for my project. I want to use a big library of assets (that I am making).

I figured that what works best for me so far is to create branches separately from the trunks to have better flexibility and more variation. But I was wondering if I could go further and generate more slightly randomized branches.

Does anyone have an idea? I am also very open to suggestions if anyone thinks a different workflow might work better.

*I am using Blender 3.0.1.
Always feel free to correct my English if my mistakes threaten comprehension or are unbearable!*